# Using inline scripts with CSP in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-security-policy

I just configured rails to use a CSP as per [the docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#content-security-policy)

My exact configuration looks like this

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self, :https
  policy.style_src   :self, :https
end

# TODO: Remove this when ready to use CSP
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_report_only = true
```

I then added `csp_meta_tag` in to `<head>` in the layout

Now when I start my application I can see that there are lots of reports about CSP violations. In my slim templates there are a few `javascript:` tags which I would like to all be allowed automatically by the CSP. This seems to be possible but I'm not quite sure how to configure it to work this way.

I would like to keep the inline script protection enabled but use the methods available to allow the inline scripts in my app even if that means adding a tag or something to each instance of an inline script.

Answer (score 0):

To allow inline scripts, you can do the following.

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  # other policies
  policy.script_src :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
end
```

Sources:
https://bauland42.com/ruby-on-rails-content-security-policy-csp/
https://rorsecurity.info/portfolio/content-security-policy-csp-strategy

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify that I still would like protect against bad inline scripts but allow the ones from my app. That first link does seem to go in to some detail about this so I will read in to it.

Comment: I see. @Qwertie You could try the nonce-based approach as described in the article on bauland42. Let us know if it works. FYI, the nonce-based approach is also written in the rails guides you linked in your question.